# asp.net gridview finding cell by datafield name or headertext name when using boundcolumns

Tags: vb.net, gridview

is it possible inside the gridview events for commands to find a cell by datafield name or headertext name
when using boundcolumns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find a column in GridView.Columns and then use its index to find a desired cell. Something like in this example:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  var myColumn = GridView1.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>().First(c => c.HeaderText == "MyColumn");
  var row = GridView1.Rows[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())];
  var cell = row.Cells[GridView1.Columns.IndexOf(myColumn)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is VB.NET:

```
Dim id As Integer = GridView.Columns.IndexOf(GridView.Columns.Cast(Of DataControlField)().First(Function(c) c.HeaderText = "Column Header"))
```